# Elastic beanstalk rails file layout structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was reading that you can still SSH into the server that has your rails code (that you deployed using elastic beanstalk).

What is the file layout like that EB creates?
Does it contain folders for previous versions that it can rollback to?

If I wanted to run sidekiq on the same server that EB uses, is that possible?

Also, I am guessing that EB will create enough processes for puma to fit into whatever memory size the instance I chose correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the instances that EB creates are just EC2 instances that you can SSH into like any other.

The file layout should be just like it is in your development environment, with the exception that it's put under `/var/app/current/`.

You can run sidekiq on the same server, though you may want to explore hosting it on a separate instance as your traffic grows.

Can't comment on puma, unfortunately.